Seasonal_decomposition with no look ahead bias
I am forecasting the demand for a certain product. The demand dataframe contains a high trend component also some seasonality, for this I don't complicate much and use the method seasonal_decompose(demand_df, model = “additive”, two_sided = False) from statsmodels. I would like that the components obtained as a result of this method do not have any kind of look ahead bias, however I think that setting two_sided = False is not enough, since the seasonal component for each month is constant, which does not make sense with a temporal evolution of the data. Does anyone have any advice on how to decompose a time series as realistically as possible (i.e. each component of the series on a given date only uses data up to the date in question). If setting two_sided = False is sufficient also let me know with some kind of mathematical explanation.
